# CSS overflow issue, div isn't containing content

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-position

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDBuK.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPbuX.png

How do I get #cols to contain the whole of #botcol's area. I realise this is quite basic but I've been struggling with it for a while, thanks for your help in advance.

Html:

```
<div id="content">
        <img id="worldmap" src="worldmap.png"/>
        <div id="cols">
            <div id="topcol">
                ...
            </div>
            <div id="botcol">
                <div id="infopanel">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
div#container{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 70%;
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
    border: grey solid 1px;
}
#cols {
    z-index:1;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
#topcol {
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
#botcol {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
div#content{
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Can you put this into a usable fiddle?

Comment: ^ Yes pleace, I am too lazy to make a fiddle for you, could you make 1 and put it here?

Comment: Just tried, got no output. Issue is its mostly white space with images, hard to view without seeing the whole file. Can you think of any css that could cause or solve this issue?

Comment: try using display:table

Comment: Tried it in a few places and no luck, which element did you want me to apply it to

Comment: Is the problem that #cols isn't high enough to contain both #topcol and #botcol? Then don't restrict the height of #cols (remove the `height` from the CSS).

Comment: @MrLister http://imgur.com/xjPef3r that happens if I remove the height:100%; from #cols

Comment: @GeorgeAppleton if you could reproduce the problem in a jsfiddle, perhaps using some random images from a site like lorempixel.com or the like, that would greatly assist in moving towards a solution. As it is now, you haven't given us the complete source, not even a link to your site, just the screen shots.

Comment: @MrLister yes sorry, I'm afraid the site isn't live currently, luckily I fixed the issue anyway :) thanks for your help though

Comment: @GeorgeAppleton Sorry. Just saw your question. I find display:table works best applied to the innermost element. However, when we do positions, it can break the element away from its "container." That shouldn't matter, here. I'd suggest applying it to #cols. But I'd debug it with FireBug, anyway, just to make sure that #infopanel is not doing the cutting off.